# forwarding a lua code to another

Tags: lua

I have lua code which I called from another lua file and wants to assign a value and to print out the value but I am getting  "nil", could you please help me.
here is the code:

```
function main_setup()

  package.path = package.path ..";C:/Users/kude/Desktop/mqtt1/?.lua"              

  require "ds18b20"

end

local a = main_setup()

print(a)
```

**output:**

> nil

Answer (score 3):

```
function main_setup()
   package.path = package.path ..";C:/Users/kude/Desktop/mqtt1/?.lua"              
   require "ds18b20"
end
```

This function does not return anything.

So

```
local a = main_setup()
```

is equivalent to

```
local a = nil
```

Hence

> nil

is the expected output of

```
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions do not implicitly return the result of the last statement.  If there is no explicit `return`, Lua implicitly `return`s `nil` – which means your code is essentially

```
function main_setup()
   package.path = package.path ..";C:/Users/kude/Desktop/mqtt1/?.lua"              
   require "ds18b20"
   return nil
end
```

---

If the file you're loading `return`s a value (or assigns it to `package.loaded`), then `require` will return that value.  To let that bubble up further, put a `return` in front of the require:

```
function main_setup()
   package.path = package.path ..";C:/Users/kude/Desktop/mqtt1/?.lua"              
   return require "ds18b20"
end
local a = main_setup()
print(a)
```